# Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm having issues with running my django app with mod_wsgi.

Here's the log message

```
[wsgi:info] [pid 21407] mod_wsgi (pid=21407): Python home /var/www/myproject/myenv.
[wsgi:info] [pid 21407] mod_wsgi (pid=21407): Initializing Python.
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

Upon checking other issues in SO and on the github page of mod_wsgi, the fix for this is to make the config point to the environment.

At this point, I'm sure that I am pointing the python home setting to the correct environment path

I also executed `sys.prefix` and it does point to `/var/www/myproject/myenv`

I'm also sure that I used the correct python version to build mod_wsgi and create the virtualenv for my project.

I was able to run `pip install -r requirements.txt` as well.

Here's my config file

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIRestrictEmbedded On

WSGIPythonHome /var/www/myproject/myenv

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py process-group=sgcdjango.com
WSGIDaemonProcess sgcdjango.com python-home=/var/www/myproject/myenv
WSGIProcessGroup myapp.com
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

<Directory /var/www/myproject/myapp/>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /static/ /var/www/myproject/static/

<Directory /var/www/myproject/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Please check the python versions used to configure mod_wsgi and the version your project is using in virtualenv. I got this error when there was a mismatch in those. Correcting that solved the issue for me.